# Xml schema, how to make sure one element exists with a specific attribute value

Tags: xml, xsd

How do I enforce the existing of an element with a specific attribute value in the XML?

For example:

```
<events>
  <event type="system" desc="this is a system event"/>
  <event type="bla1" desc="this is bla1 event"/>
  <event type="bla2" desc="this is bla2 event"/>
</events>
```

I need a rule to make sure the event element with type attribute = 'system' exists (once).
All other event elements are optional;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you're using XML Schema 1.0**, you cannot express the constraint directly.  You could do it outside of XML Schema 1.0 via Schematron or XSLT directly.

**If you're using XML Schema 1.1**, you can [specify co-occurrence constraints](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/) via `xs:assert`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0">
  <xs:element name="events">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="event" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="desc" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="count(event[@type = 'system']) = 1"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can't use v1.1 schema, Microsoft is always years behind in supporting W3C recommendations. I must use MSXML