# Is it possible to xsd-validate is an element with exact Attribute exists?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, key-value, xml-attribute

I am planning to receive that structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document>
    <property key="DocumentType"   value="INV" />
    <property key="InvInternalNumber" value="i-1651-84" />
    <property key="OtherDynamicProperty" value="yes" />
</Document>
```

I identify document type and going to validate with "INV.xsd"

Oh, business say that Invoice must have "InvInternalNumber" property!

So,
Is it possible to xsd validate "Is there a property "InvInternalNumber" "  ?

**UPDATE**
That XSD has been generated by JaxbContext.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="Document" type="Document"/>

  <xs:complexType name="Document">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="property" type="property" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="property">
    <xs:sequence/>
    <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: That's a pretty basic XML schema validation rule? Have you tried a "xs:attribute" validation rule in your schema file? Check out this example: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_example.asp

Comment: Can you also please post the INV.xsd schema you've set up? I think your concern is rather a writing rule than a structure validation... So we might use a different approach.

Comment: Is the XML an unordered list of keys and values, or can you assume a specific order of a known list of keys? Perhaps the answer to this SO question works for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543806/xml-schema-how-to-make-sure-one-element-exists-with-a-specific-attribute-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSD 1.0 isn't designed for this job: it assumes that the element name determines the validation rules to apply. One way to tackle it is to transform the XML (using XSLT) to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document>
    <DocumentType>INV</DocumentType>
    <InvInternalNumber>i-1651-84</InvInternalNumber>
    <OtherDynamicProperty>yes</OtherDynamicProperty>
</Document>
```

and then validate that. (You can achieve this in a single step by using a schema-aware transformation and validating the result document).

Where the validation rules are determined not by the element name, but by the value of an attribute (in your case `property/@key`), the new feature of Conditional Type Assignment in XSD 1.1 can be used. This allows you to declare that the type of the `property` element (and hence, the type of its `value` attribute) depends on the value of the `key` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not possible in XSD 1.0, I thought if you made the assumption that *InvInternalNumber* was always the first element you may be able to use the **fixed** attribute to do it like this, but unfortunately this is not valid.

> Error cos-element-consistent: Error for type 'Document'. Multiple elements with name 'property', with different types, appear in the model group.

So as @Dag says I think the only solution is available in XSD 1.1 in the [link provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543806/xml-schema-how-to-make-sure-one-element-exists-with-a-specific-attribute-value).

[image]